# How do I release a CGImageRef in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, cgimageref

I am writing this method to calculate the average R,G,B values of an image. The following method takes a UIImage as an input and returns an array containing the R,G,B values of the input image. I have one question though: How/Where do I properly release the CGImageRef?

```
-(NSArray *)getAverageRGBValuesFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef rawImageRef = [image CGImage];

    //This function returns the raw pixel values
    const UInt8 *rawPixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(rawImageRef)));

    NSUInteger imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(rawImageRef);
    NSUInteger imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(rawImageRef);

    //Here I sort the R,G,B, values and get the average over the whole image
    int i = 0;
    unsigned int red = 0;
    unsigned int green = 0;
    unsigned int blue = 0;

    for (int column = 0; column< imageWidth; column++)
    {
        int r_temp = 0;
        int g_temp = 0;
        int b_temp = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < imageHeight; row++) {
            i = (row * imageWidth + column)*4;
            r_temp += (unsigned int)rawPixelData[i];
            g_temp += (unsigned int)rawPixelData[i+1];
            b_temp += (unsigned int)rawPixelData[i+2];

        }

        red += r_temp;
        green += g_temp;
        blue += b_temp;

    }

    NSNumber *averageRed = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0*red)/(imageHeight*imageWidth)];
    NSNumber *averageGreen = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0*green)/(imageHeight*imageWidth)];
    NSNumber *averageBlue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0*blue)/(imageHeight*imageWidth)];


    //Then I store the result in an array
    NSArray *result = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:averageRed,averageGreen,averageBlue, nil];


    return result;
}
```

I tried two things: 
Option 1:
I leave it as it is, but then after a few cycles (5+) the program crashes and I get the "low memory warning error"

Option 2:
I add one line
CGImageRelease(rawImageRef) 
before the method returns. Now it crashes after the second cycle, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for the UIImage that I pass to the method. When I try to analyze (instead of RUN) in Xcode I get the following warning at this line 
"Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

Where and how should I release the CGImageRef?

Thanks!

Comment: One way to find these things is to go Product→Analyze, and the analyzer will find this memory handling error for you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your memory issue results from the copied data, as others have stated. But here's another idea: Use Core Graphics's optimized pixel interpolation to calculate the average.

1. Create a 1x1 bitmap context.
2. Set the interpolation quality to medium (see later).
3. Draw your image scaled down to exactly this one pixel.
4. Read the RGB value from the context's buffer.
5. (Release the context, of course.)

This might result in better performance because Core Graphics is highly optimized and might even use the GPU for the downscaling.

Testing showed that medium quality seems to interpolate pixels by taking the average of color values. That's what we want here.

Worth a try, at least.

**Edit:** OK, this idea seemed too interesting not to try. So [here's an example project](https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/UIImageAverageColor) showing the difference. Below measurements were taken with the contained 512x512 test image, but you can change the image if you want.

It takes about 12.2 ms to calculate the average by iterating over all pixels in the image data. The draw-to-one-pixel approach takes 3 ms, so it's roughly 4 times faster. It seems to produce the same results when using `kCGInterpolationQualityMedium`.

I assume that the huge performance gain is a result from Quartz noticing that it does not have to decompress the JPEG fully but that it can use the lower frequency parts of the DCT only. That's an interesting optimization strategy when composing JPEG compressed pixels with a scale below 0.5. But I'm only guessing here.

Interestingly, when using your method, 70% of the time is spent in `CGDataProviderCopyData` and only 30% in the pixel data traversal. This hints to a lot of time spent in JPEG decompression.

[image: Pixel Iterating Screenshot] [image: Draw-To-One-Pixel Screenshot]

Note: [Here's a late follow up](https://pudding.cool/2021/10/lenna/) on the example image above.

Comment: @Jonny Calculating the average for non-rectangular areas could easily be done by setting a clip (path or mask) before drawing. The clip would render some pixels transparent which means they would not affect the final result. Tada!

Comment: OK I might be looking to extend this class with such a feature. Oh I'm just trying to code a "magic wand" for selecting the face area having a similar skin color/tone.

Comment: Testing seems to show that alpha sampling done by Core Graphics does not produce the expected average. Without further digging into this topic I'd not recommend using this approach for non-rectangular areas.

Comment: What's the difference between Average and Merged color?? Thanks for the code!!

Comment: @Daniel "Average" is just the straight forward code that walks over all pixels and computes the average. "Merged" is the proposed implementation that actually draws the image and uses the result as the average color.

Answer (score 8):

You don't own the `CGImageRef` `rawImageRef` because you obtain it using  `[image CGImage]`. So you don't need to release it.

However, you own `rawPixelData` because you obtained it using [`CGDataProviderCopyData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html) and must release it.

> **CGDataProviderCopyData**
>
> Return Value:
> A new data object containing a copy of the provider’s data. You are responsible for releasing this object.

Comment: ... which you'd do by keeping the `CFDataRef` it returns and calling `CFRelease` on that at the appropriate moment. Be careful that the norm here is the exact opposite of the Objective-C norm; if you pass `CFRelease(NULL)` then Core Foundation will very deliberately raise an exception.

Comment: @Tommy Of course, as there is a big difference between `nil` in Obj-C and `NULL` in plain C.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your issue is in this statement:

```
const UInt8 *rawPixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(rawImageRef)));
```

You should be releasing the return value of CGDataProviderCopyData.

Answer (score 4):

Your mergedColor works great on an image loaded from a file, but not for an image capture by the camera. Because `CGBitmapContextGetData()` on the context created from a captured sample buffer doesn't return it bitmap. I changed your code to as following. It works on any image and it is as fast as your code.

```
- (UIColor *)mergedColor
{
     CGImageRef rawImageRef = [self CGImage];

    // scale image to an one pixel image

    uint8_t  bitmapData[4];
    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;
    int width = 1;
    int height = 1;

    bitmapBytesPerRow = (width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * height);
    memset(bitmapData, 0, bitmapByteCount);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,width,height,8,bitmapBytesPerRow,
             colorspace,kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little|kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationMedium);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), rawImageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:bitmapData[2] / 255.0f
                    green:bitmapData[1] / 255.0f
                             blue:bitmapData[0] / 255.0f
                            alpha:1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CFDataRef abgrData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(rawImageRef));

const UInt8 *rawPixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(abgrData);

...

CFRelease(abgrData);
```