# Resize MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, frame

Looks like simple task. But when I try to resize using **setFrame** method I got glitches. There are some other UIViews resized using **setFrame** method and it works perfectly. I made custom application with slider bar and map view. SlideBar changes X position for MKMapView, but keeps width equals to screen width. This approach works fine for all Views. But MKMapView resizes with smooth troubles. Can anyone please give a clue why it's happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which seems to occur only on iOS 6 (Apple Maps) and not on iOS 5 (Google Maps).

My solution was to take a "screenshot" of the map when the user start dragging the divider handle, replace the map with this screenshot during the drag, and put the map back when the finger is released.

I used the code from [How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) for UIView screenshot and Nikolai Ruhe's answer at [How do I release a CGImageRef in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147779/how-do-i-release-a-cgimageref-in-ios/12148136#12148136) for a nice background color.

My UIPanGestureRecognizer action is something like this (the `(MKMapView)self.map` is a subview of `(UIView)self.mapContainer` with autoresizing set on Interface Builder):

```
- (IBAction)handleMapPullup:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.mapContainer];

    // save current map center
    static CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate;

    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            // Save map center coordinate
            centerCoordinate = self.map.centerCoordinate;

            // Take a "screenshot" of the map and set the size adjustments
            UIImage *mapScreenshot = [UIImage imageWithView:self.map];
            self.mapImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:mapScreenshot];
            self.mapImage.autoresizingMask = self.map.autoresizingMask;
            self.mapImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
            self.mapImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
            self.mapImage.backgroundColor = [mapScreenshot mergedColor];

            // Replace the map with a screenshot
            [self.map removeFromSuperview];
            [self.mapContainer insertSubview:self.mapImage atIndex:0];
        } break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            break;

        default:
            // Resize the map to the new dimension
            self.map.frame = self.mapImage.frame;

            // Replace the screenshot with the resized map
            [self.mapImage removeFromSuperview];
            [self.mapContainer insertSubview:self.map atIndex:0];

            // Empty screenshot memory
            self.mapImage = nil;
            break;
    }

    // resize map container according do the translation value
    CGRect mapFrame = self.mapContainer.frame;
    mapFrame.size.height += translation.y;

    // reset translation to make a relative read on next event
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.mapContainer];

    self.mapContainer.frame = mapFrame;
    self.map.centerCoordinate = centerCoordinate; // keep center
}
```