# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with CGImageRef

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, cgimage

I have a function:

```
- (UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(CGFloat)resizedWidth height:(CGFloat)resizedHeight shouldCrop:(BOOL)crop
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, 8, 4 * resizedWidth, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

    if (crop) // for SmallImage (tableviewcell)
    {
        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, CGImageGetHeight(ref) * 0.5 - ((float) kIvHeight * 0.5), (float) kIvWidth, (float) kIvHeight);
        ref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(ref, cropRect);
    }

    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

The line `CGImageRelease(imageRef);` causes my app to crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
it seems to work when I remove the line - but would this not cause memory leaks?

Comment: does this line somehow deallocate the original UIImage? (the image parameter)

Comment: You have to call CGImageRelease only when you use CGImageCreate, Copy or Retain. you dont need to call CGImageRelease in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't own the `CGImageRef imageRef` because you obtain it using `[image CGImage]` so you don't need to release it.

Take a look at this one as well: [How do I release a CGImageRef in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147779/how-do-i-release-a-cgimageref-in-ios)